# Unibody Macbook Stuck on Apple Logo

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, unibody

My White, Unibody Macbook running OS X 10.8 started to freeze, so I shut it down.

When I went to restart it, it got stuck on the Apple Logo for some five minutes before I just turned it back off.

So far, I have:

- Checked & Repaired Disk
- Checked & Repaired Permissions
- Reset the NVRAM
- Reset the SMC
- Tried Safe Boot

For Safe Boot, the loading bar appeared and it started to load. Then, it disappeared and I got stuck with the progress indicator (again) for some eight minutes before I just turned it off.

I need my Macbook for school and all, it has all my work and projects...

Any thoughts? Any input is welcome.

*Note: My Apple Care subscription expired < 1 month ago, so... :(*

**Edit**

In response to a comment below, I booted up using <kbd>CMD + V</kbd>. Here are the results:

```
...
** /dev/rdisk0s2 (NO WRITE)
** Root file system
    Executing fsck_hfs (version diskdev_cmds-557~393)
FIPS USER Space POST: Integrity test success!
FIPS USER Space POST: AES GCM test success!
FIPS USER Space POST: AES CBC test success!
FIPS USER Space POST: TDES CBC test success!
FIPS USER Space POST: SHA test success!
FIPS USER Space POST: HMAC test success!
FIPS USER Space POST: RSA test success!
FIPS USER Space POST: ECDSA test success!
FIPS USER Space POST: DRBG test success!
FIPS USER Space POST Success!
```

And then nothing...

Comment: Try to boot in verbose mode by holding `cmd+V` during the boot process. This will show you all the messages during startup and eventually show you where the MacBook hangs. Post back with result so people can help you with a more specific question.

Comment: @BartArondson updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple geniuses have a lot of latitude with what they can do. I have gotten a motherboard replacement about 2 weeks after my 3 year Apple Care plan expired. If you go to the store and are honest you could get lucky. I haven't heard of anybody getting service after a month. At the least the genius can tell you for sure what the problem is.

So make a genius bar appointment and see what they say. With Apple it really doesn't hurt to ask.

Comment: I would second this sentiment. The main thing a genius appointment will do is cut through all the things you need to accomplish: 1) backup data 2) rule out software issues 3) diagnose the hardware and it's all for free if you can get into a store - AppleCare current or not.

Answer (score 0):

Checked and repaired disk how?

Start up in single-user mode, Command-S, and run FSCK -Y at the prompt, or FSCK -F if journalled, and if results say, File System Modifed, run it again until that message goes away, then reboot.

Single User Startup info: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1492

This is a good example of why a disk clone comes in handy, now that we don't have Install Disks ... not only to have a copy of everything on your machine, but also as a Startup Disk, from which can be run Disk Utility and, if you have it, the one utility worth buying, Disk Warrior. See CarbonCopyCloner or SuperDuper.

Comment: I checked and repaired the disk via the Recovery Partition (CMD + R). I'll try `FSCK` when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

```
** /dev/rdisk0s2 (NO WRITE)
** Root file system
    Executing fsck_hfs (version diskdev_cmds-557~393)
FIPS USER Space POST: Integrity test success!
FIPS USER Space POST: AES GCM test success!
FIPS USER Space POST: AES CBC test success!
FIPS USER Space POST: TDES CBC test success!
FIPS USER Space POST: SHA test success!
FIPS USER Space POST: HMAC test success!
FIPS USER Space POST: RSA test success!
FIPS USER Space POST: ECDSA test success!
FIPS USER Space POST: DRBG test success!
FIPS USER Space POST Success!
```

I seems if your hd is not writing its reading though you need a new hd sorry back up your files.